# Do command line applications like emacs use normal stdin/stdout?

Tags: command-line

Almost all of the applications I've ever written have been GUIs of one form or another - HTML/Flex/Swing - and the bulk of my command line apps have been extremely simple, without much interaction. The most I've ever done is make a simple ascii game that just does a print/input loop, printing the game board over and over again.

I was thinking about doing something a little more complex, and I was really curious how some of the more advanced command line apps like emacs even work. Specifically, I have no idea how they seem to be able to have an interactive command line that responds to key presses and appears to just operate on a buffer in the terminal instead of constantly going through the print->read->print loop. Is it all just stdin/stdout kung fu I'm not aware of or is it something completely different?

**Update** - I want to be clear that I'm not trying to ask a broad question here, perhaps I'm just having difficulty finding the right words. Basically, I don't know how I would make emacs work using stdin/stdout. Is it using some mechanism I'm not aware of, and if so, what?

Comment: +1 Interested in the answer for this.

Comment: @Cameron - Why? It's not a discussion, it's a real question that has a very real specific answer, I just can't seem to find the right terms to use in google.

Comment: It feels a little broad to me, but that's just my opinion. I don't feel strongly enough to have voted to close :) Don't get me wrong; I'm interested in the answer, just not sure if it's more appropriate for `programmers` or not.

Comment: Now that I think about it a bit more I retract my suggestion. Comment removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that it isn't just stdin/stdout for a program like this.  Usually it's a *terminal control library* such as [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29).

Some other arbitrarily-chosen libraries include:

- [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)
- [Rexio](http://www.rexio.org/)

See also [Text user interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_user_interface) on Wikipedia.

I'm not very familiar with using any of those libraries, but [the current version of terminfo.c in the emacs source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/terminfo.c?h=emacs-23) has the following comment, suggesting they do use curses:

> ```
> /* Interface to curses/terminfo library.
>    Turns out that all of the terminfo-level routines look
>    like their termcap counterparts except for tparm, which replaces
>    tgoto.  Not only is the calling sequence different, but the string
>    format is different too.
> */
> ```

Comment: emacs is decidedly a **termcap** application, making no use of the high-level curses library.